# How do I reset the 3d view from this state?

Tags: 3d-view, interface

I am new to Blender. I have some experience with 3DS Max though.

I was trying to use the little triangular widgets at the bottom left and top right of a tab, and eventually ended up with 18 of them before I learned how to get rid of SOME of them. I am left with the Blender window below, and cannot get rid of whatever this is, to show me the usual 3D window any more. If I close blender and restart and load the same .blend file, I get the same result.

[image: Messed-up Blender window]

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should probably edit the title so that it reflects your problem otherwise no one will bother clicking on it.  Something like  "how do I reset the 3d view"

Comment: you may want to read through the manual section on ui: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/interface/window_system/introduction.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press the button next to the word Default. It will display a bunch of preset views to choose from. However you have corrupted the Default 3d view. So go down to the bottom of that large window with the line on it and look for the clock icon in the corner. You have expanded the Timeline view. Click the clock and choose the 3d view symbol instead

Answer (score 0):

[image]

To fix this, we will start by removing the timeline and adding back the *3D View*. To do that, click on the *View Selector* in the bottom left, and click in the *3D View* option.

Now to remove the info section, just place the mouse cursor in the bridge area as shown in the picture until the resize cursor takes over, and then drag it to the top.

Answer (score 0):

Save the file, and open that file again with blender but make sure to untick the Load UI box.

Cheers

[image: Save the file, and open that file again with blender but make sure to untick the Load UI box]